# Is an exception thrown when I'm stopping the program?

Tags: python, exception, keyboardinterrupt

I'm writing some program in python, and whenever I stop the program deliberatly (from the stop button in the PyCharm client) I want the program to execute some more commands before stopping. Is an exception thrown when I stop the program? I tried to add a try except with KeyboardInterrupt exception but it didn't work.

Comment: Suggest you look at the [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html#module-atexit) module — which may make your question moot.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch [KeyboardInterrupt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt) errors.

Try to run this script and kill it and you will see that `KeyboardInterrupt happened!` will be printed:

```
import time
try:
    time.sleep(5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("KeyboardInterrupt happened!")
    raise
```

Comment: As I said in the question, I tried that already and for some reason that doesn't work. Perhaps IntelliJ stops the program differently, without using KeyboardInterrupt?

Comment: Strange, it works for me in Pycharm. Did you try to catch `SystemExit` - `except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):`

Comment: Still doesn't work. Thanks for familiarizing me with syntax of catching multiple exceptions though :)